# Determine OS using javascript

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I am looking for a generic way in Javascript of obtaining the client's operating system. Many documented solutions use the user agent and I have come across similar questions/answers on stack overflow which are outdated. A sample function is provided below but I am wondering are there more comprehensive versions which meet the following guidelines:

- All modern and widely used OS should have a version, for example instead of just *Windows*, have  *Windows 10* or *Windows 7*
- Older and largely redundant OSes can be grouped together, e.g. *Windows 98*, *Windows Vista* could appear as just *Windows*
- Mobile OSes need to be included too with versions where possible, e.g. *Android 7.0*
- The code shouldn't be excessively long, the aim is to distinguish between the current most popular systems.

The example below was put together without too much thought and I am looking for a better version of it

```
function getOS() {
  var osStr;
  var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

  if (ua.indexOf("windows xp") !== -1) {
    osStr = "WindowsXP";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("windows nt 6.1") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Windows7";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("windows nt 10.0") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Windows10";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("iemobile") !== -1 || ua.indexOf("windows phone") !== -1) {
    osStr = "WindowsMobile";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("windows") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Windows";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("ipad") !== -1) {
    osStr = "ipad";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("ipod") !== -1) {
    osStr = "iTouch)";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("iphone") !== -1) {
    osStr = "iPhone)";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("cros") !== -1) {
    osStr = "ChromeOS";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("android") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Android";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("blackberry") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Blackberry";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("palm") !== -1) {
    osStr = "PalmOS";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("kindle") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Kindle";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("ubuntu") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Ubuntu";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("linux") !== -1) {
    osStr = "Linux";
  } else if (ua.indexOf("nix") !== -1) {
    osStr = "UNIX";
  } else {
    osStr = "Unknown";
  }

  return osStr;
}
```

Comment: An obvious question would be "why"? How does knowing the OS benefit you?

Comment: There are several libraries that can do this.  Some better than others.  But in general *feature detection* is preferred over browser identification.

Comment: @CarlMarkham why does your comment have 3 upvotes and why did you ask why?  Do you think perhaps the OP's sanity is in question? Can you really not think of single reason why it would not be beneficial for a web page to know the OS of the visiting user? https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Woah woah, I was only asking the why. Maybe the answer would have provided more information or a better answer to the question. The OP's sanity was never in question @BrianOgden. If you can't ask why on a question/answer forum then where can you?

Comment: BTW, those `else if`s don't look very sane, IMHO... Sorry for being off-topic.

Comment: @CarlMarkham The why is do conditionally do something after determining the client's OS :)

Comment: @BrianOgden That's not the "why", that's the "goal" :)

Comment: @BrianOgden Someone posts a question on SO and it's none of my business to question the "why" regardless of whether it helps answer the question or not? Since when was asking "why" a bad thing?

Anyway, lets not digress from the question, the debate has been fun but let's end it and hopefully someone can answer OP's question :)

Comment: @CarlMarkham When I ask a question on SO, the why I am trying to do something is not actually anyone's business, I have my reasons. Perhaps it is just curiosity if it can be done. If my question is clear, reproducible & concise and my code is of the same vein, it is no one's business as to why I am trying to code something the way I am, in many cases. Now sometimes the approach is just completely wrong the why is very important. But I do not think that is the case with this question :), cheers.

Comment: The os is one part of a os_browsername string which I'd like to send from the client to server. Even though my webapp uses javascript feature detection, the UX is different on various platforms and having this data  will give an indication of which platforms are working well and which may be problematical.  Problematical widely used platforms can be investigated further.

Comment: Here is my "why". On windows, the key for selecting multiple non-contiguous items is Ctrl; on Mac it is Command. On windows, we would see if event.ctrlKey is pressed, and on Mac we should check if event.metaKey is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking to combine the OS with the user agent into a single string and the UAParser library at https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js (found through the answer above) works well for both. The library is currently up to date and looks like it is maintained well. Its minified version is 19KB. Created a function

```
  function getPlatform() {
      var uap = UAParser(navigator.userAgent);
      var osVersion = uap.os.version;
      if (osVersion == null) {
        osVersion = "";
      }
      var browserVersion = uap.browser.major;
      if (browserVersion == null) {
        browserVersion = "";
      }

      var platform = uap.os.name + osVersion + "_" + uap.browser.name + browserVersion;
      platform = platform.replace(/\s/g, '');

      return platform;
  }
```

which when called returns a no whitespace string *OS_UA* which is forwarded as part of the URL from client to server.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different user agents strings see http://www.user-agents.org/

It would be impractical to sift through them all. Depending on your use case, it would be more beneficial to filter out those that you care about.

There are APIs that you can use however, which have already done the hardwork for you 
https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/api/features/user-agent-parse is a great tool that will parse user agent strings for you

Here is a more comprehensive list with examples for each
https://www.whatsmyua.info/

Comment: That last link (i.e. https://www.whatsmyua.info/) looks useful.  A quick look at its offerings suggest that https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js is up to date and will serve my purposes. Okay its not as compact as I would have perhaps liked but is self contained and comprehensive. The other suggestions may also work.